# Google Sheets ARRAYFORMULA to Ignore data that exists alone

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the formula '=TRANSPOSE({B2:B25&",&TRANSPOSE(C2:C25))' in the d2 cell, and I want to make the color or size data not come out alone as shown [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kxfN.jpg)
In addition, if it can do so, I would like to be able to organize them all in one column sequentially (ex.RED,SB→ORANGE,SS..)

=TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula({B2:B25&","&TRANSPOSE(C2:C25)}))
=TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(IF((A2:A20<>"")*(B2:B20<>""),{A2:A20&","&TRANSPOSE(B2:B20)},)))
=TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(IF((A2:A20<>"")*(B2:B20<>""),{A2:A20&","&B2:B20},IF(A2:A20="", B2:B20, A2:A20))))

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
=tocol(index(tocol(A2:A,1)&","&torow(B2:B,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: @HKJIN If this answer helps you to solve the problem then please consider to accept it (tick mark the answer) so that other can know the thread is solved.

Comment: Nice trick applied.